# Python updating class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have simplified the problem like this.

program.py

```
from classB import B
myClass = B(7)
myClass.print__()
myClass.bbb = 8
print(myClass.bbb)
myClass.print__()
```

classA.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.aaa = a

    def print_(self):
        print(self.aaa)
```

classB.py

```
from classA import A
class B:
    def __init__(self, bb):
        self.bbb = bb
        self.Aclass = A(self.bbb)

    def print__(self):
        self.Aclass.print_()
```

In program.py, I created a classB instance myClass, and initialized with 7. If then, from classB.py, a classA instance Aclass will be created, and also be initialized with 7, so when I call print__(), it shows that Aclass is also initialized with 7.

The problem here is when I updated myClass.bbb to 8, I also expected Aclass.aaa to be 8, but it didn't.

I might solve this by making another function like update_varA(), but could you please explain why this happens, and a better solution to this?

Comment: You should understand two things: first, integers are immutable; second, `a = 7`does not modify the object which was previously in `a` - it just puts a different object (7) into `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the update function. In your case it would be (in classB.py)

```
class B:
    def update_value(self, new_value):
        self.bbb = new_value
        self.AClass.aaa = new_value

    [... all the other functions]
```

Another way would be to set the value directly in your main routine (program.py)

```
myClass.AClass.aaa = 8
```

would to the trick.

If you want to dive in a little deeper, you could also override the `__setattr__()` function. Basically, when you do something like

```
myClass.bbb = 8
```

python does this under the hood:

```
myClass.__setattr__('bbb', 8)
```

myClass is acutually an instance of the class here btw, so the name is a little misleading. Nevertheless, you can override the **setattr**():

```
class B:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name=='bbb':
            self.bbb = new_value
            self.AClass.aaa = new_value
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)

    [... all the other functions]
```

but this is quite advanced. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Comment: If bbb was not a number, and was mutable like list, then would my code work?

Comment: I don't think so... but you could just try it yourself :) Experimenting with a language is one of the quickest ways to learn it!

Comment: Capturing the update action through overwritting the `setattr` was useful for my purposes, thanks for elaborating on that.